# Rails: elasticsearch error deploying to EC2 with Rubber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2

When running `cap rubber:create_staging` I get the following error:

```
   * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: '  bash -l /tmp/install_elasticsearch"
     servers: ["test5.foo.com"]
     [test5.foo.com] executing command
     command finished in 1640ms
failed: "/bin/bash -l -c 'sudo -p '\\''sudo password: '\\''  bash -l /tmp/install_elasticsearch'" on test5.foo.com
```

Everything seems to be going okay. I've tried updating the gems to the most recent versions but the error still persists. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The endpoint for elastic search changed :/
**The fix is out:** [here you go](https://github.com/wr0ngway/rubber/commit/ed796b761334f13dfc6f0b9c66314b404cf465f4)
:)